# Phonegap + QR Scanner + Iphone

Tags: jquery, iphone, cordova

I am building Iphone application using phonegap. I am trying to include simple QR scanner. and I am looking for the best solution. I tried XZing but I faced alot of bugs with lack of tutorials...

any advice for any other solutions ???

Comment: AFAIK, XZing is the best one to use with phonegap, and i think it's not buggy.

Answer (score 0):

You should just use the [BarcodeScanner](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/BarcodeScanner) plugin which uses ZXing under the hood.

Comment: OK thank you ... now I just finished include the XZing to my project ... now how I can start scanning QR ... I download the BarcodeScanner example but it has 1 error